# How can I run a PowersShell script remotely as admin without requiring any additional prompt?

Tags: powershell, permissions, admin, remote-access, psexec

I have a script I will run remotely on a computer with a privileged user account using PsExec. To access certain registry hives in `HKEY_USERS`, the script must run from PowerShell under "Run as Administrator".

Since I am running this remotely, I wont be able to click "Yes" when it usually asks if I want to allow PowerShell to run as admin. How can I do all this remotely and from a script?

I have tried the following command, but it requires me to press a prompt afterwards:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

Comment: This is mutually exclusive: _privileged user account_ and _Administrator_. So you should either run script under Administrator account or under that privileged user account. You cannot do both when running script remotely and using unattended execution. Using psexec -h as proposed by StephenP below will effectively do the same as running script from Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

Questions should include [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show what you have tried with sample code and ask specific questions about specific errors. In your case you are probably looking for the [-h parameter of psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using powershell remoting (enter-pssession)? I'm not sure but I don't think when remoting using an administrator account it will prompt.